# SQL command not properly ended with DELETE transsaction

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I have 3 tables

> FLUX_ISU_FORMULE

```
ID  NUMBER(38,0)
CPT_CODE    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
TYPE_ENERGIE    VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)
DATE_MODIFICATION   DATE
```

> FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL

```
ID  NUMBER(38,0)
FRM_ID  NUMBER(38,0) -- FLUX_ISU_FORMULE ID
DATE_DEBUT  DATE
DATE_FIN    DATE
```

FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU

```
ID  NUMBER(38,0)
FRM_ID  NUMBER(38,0) -- FLUX_ISU_FORMULE ID
FCL_ID  NUMBER(38,0) -- FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL ID
CADRAN  NUMBER(38,0)
EQU_CODE    NUMBER(38,0)
COEFFICIENT NUMBER(38,0)
```

I have to delete data from my tables according to its rules of managements:

CADRAN ═ 1 or 4 (the other tables are deleted, no error message).
TYPE_ENERGIE starting with "EA" (EA should accept uppercase and lowercase), the other type of energy are not integrated (the others are deleted tables, no error message).

I do this

```
DELETE
FROM FLUX_ISU_FORMULE
INNER JOIN FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL
ON FLUX_ISU_FORMULE.ID = FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL.FRM_ID
INNER JOIN FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU
ON FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL.FRM_ID = FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU.FRM_ID
AND FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL.ID    = FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU.FCL_ID
WHERE lower(FLUX_ISU_FORMULE.type_energie) NOT LIKE 'ea%'
AND (FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU.CADRAN <> 1 AND FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU.CADRAN  <> 4);
```

I have this Error:

> Erreur à la ligne de commande : 2, colonne : 21 Rapport d'erreur :
>   Erreur SQL : ORA-00933: la commande SQL ne se termine pas correctement
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM FLUX_ISU_FORMULE  WHERE
(FLUX_ISU_FORMULE.ID) IN
(SELECT FLUX_ISU_FORMULE.ID
FROM FLUX_ISU_FORMULE
INNER JOIN FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL
ON FLUX_ISU_FORMULE.ID = FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL.FRM_ID
INNER JOIN FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU
ON FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL.FRM_ID = FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU.FRM_ID
AND FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_CL.ID    = FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU.FCL_ID
WHERE lower(FLUX_ISU_FORMULE.type_energie) NOT LIKE 'ea%'
AND (FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU.CADRAN <> 1 AND FLUX_ISU_FORMULE_TAB_EQU.CADRAN  <> 4));
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not support JOIN for the DELETE statement which is clearly documented in the manual.

You need to rewrite it using co-related sub-selects.

Comment: Ok, How can make a Delete statement with the Query Builder ?

Comment: @Mercer: I have no idea what that "Query Builder" is. You should ask in a forum for that "Builder" how you can tell it to generate valid Oracle syntax.